# Passing multiple fields values to ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, search, ransack

I have Rails app with a table and I want to have search fields on top of each column which should perform search on the column and those searches should work together. So I'm looking for a way to implement it and stumbled upon Ransack gem which looks nice with all it's selecting and sorting functionality but I can't understand if I can use it to solve my problem.

From the documentation I see that I can pass a parameter to it like this
`User.ransack(first_name_cont: 'Rya').result.to_sql`

But I think it's not enough for my problem and I need something like
`User.ransack(first_name_cont: 'Foo', last_name_eq: 'Bar', middle_name_in: [Moo, Boo]).result.to_sql`

Can I do something like this with Ransack? Or how else can I solve my problem with it or maybe I should use something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ransack takes responsibility of searching on each field to himself. So you specify any field, which exist in your table, in search.

You can combine any field with predicates. For example you have field `age`:

```
 User.ransack(age_eq: 21) # => age = 21
 User.ransack(age_lt: 21) # => age < 21
 User.ransack(age_in: [21]) # => age in [21]
```

Combine with another field 'name':

```
User.ransack(age_lt: 21, name_eq: 'Tim') # => age < 21 AND name = 'Tim'
User.ransack(age_gteq: 21, name_eq: 'Tom') # => age >= 21 AND name = 'Tom'
```

You can pass multiple values by using `in` predicate or `not_in` for opposite operation.

And more, [see basic predicates with description](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Basic-Searching).

Comment: ok. I read this docs and was confused by that fact that all the examples there use only one parameter. So that's why I didn't know if it's possible to pass many. I'm new to Rails. So probably it's just my lacking of Rails fundumentals knowledge

Comment: @SeyboGlaux If you think about lacking of knowledge, you can read this article http://blog.mediumequalsmessage.com/6-best-learning-ruby-books

Comment: and can I ask how would you implement it? Would you just make ordinary search fields on top of the columns or would you use Ransack `search_form_for` helper for it? I tried to use it on my table `td`s with `f.search_field` inside and couldn't make it work like this

Comment: @SeyboGlaux Can you please append code(to question)

Comment: @SeyboGlaux Can you post the snippet of the `search_form_for` Ransack helper? the implementation?